# Сообщение о правке, выполненной другим участником

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация

Интересное (и непереведенное) сообщение выскочило в шапке сайта в процессе редактирования сообщения низкого качества:

[image: шапка рыжая]

> This post has been edited 1 times since you began. Your edit can only be saved if it is more thorough than the currently saved edit.

Ещё момент в том, что данный баннер не исчезает при переходе к следующему сообщению в очереди (хотя по идее, наверное, должен бы).

Comment: Вынесите предложение перевода в качестве ответа

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Предлагаю следующий перевод:

> Текущее сообщение было отредактировано 1 раз с момента начала вашей правки. Ваша правка может быть сохранена только если она более полная, чем сохраненная.

Добавил перевод на [transifex](https://www.transifex.com/stack-exchange/stack-overflow-ru/translate/#ru/english/84062440?q=This%20post%20has%20been%20edited). Требуется утверждение.